# How to apply parent class to all BrowserRouter Routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

A simplified version of what I am trying to do is as follows:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="randomClassName">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

This pattern works perfectly in development but when built for production it hangs on loading the initial rout "/".

The parent class in this situation would represent some adjustable styling information that is pulled from a database and I know there are npm packages I can use to manipulate the head or style components directly.  However, I would just really like to know why this isn't working and why it only happens in the build config.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Redirect in the below manner. It actually depends on the server configuration, the way it is configured to serve your index.html. Can you share the server details that you are using in dev env and in prod env in the comment ? Meanwhile, below should fix the issue.

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <div className="randomClassName">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, the redirect did not solve the problem.     I'm working in create-react-app with redux, firestore, firebase, and reactReduxFirebase managing the two.  Here is a link to the github: https://github.com/danielmeeusen/react-fb-clientpanel

Comment: I can see two routes for Dashboard in your Routes.js. Can you remove `<Route exact path="/" component={UserIsAuthenticated(Dashboard)} />`  and try again ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried all version of directing and redirecting to dashboard.  None worked.  I just pushed my latest version with only one dashboard route, however, I worked around the problem by using localStorage as a median between the DB and browserrouter.  I read in the documentation that it can't work within redux, which I am thinking may have been the problem.  So I got rid of redux for that particular component and it solved it.  Although changing the theme now requires the page to be refreshed which isn't quite as aesthetically pleasing.  If you have any thoughts I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Well I use the similar configuration and I use react and redux. I dont use Firebase set up though an my route redirections work properly. Can you share the link where it says it doesnt work with Redux ?

Comment: Link is above.  Number 1 in the blocked updates is what I think applies to my case.  I reverted the github back to the way I originally had it if you'd like to take a look.  I don't think that it is because I am using redux inherrently but that I am using redux connect to sync it with firestore.  I'm not sure but I think they are both trying to access the same point in the component life cycle.