# How do I change body background, depending on which component is showing on screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm creating an e-commerce website using React Hooks and Router. Currently I have a blank home page, sign up and log in page. I want my background to change when the route changes to /signup. How do I add a background image when the Signup component loads? Below is my App component.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path ='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: BrowserRouter is badly pasted here, it is ok in my source code

Comment: Is `Signup` a lazy loaded component?

Comment: 2 options: one is to set bg color on each component and make is full screen, the other way is use redux or other state management tool

Comment: I guess you can wrap all the routes with an element and dynamically change the classname using the path. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52807951/how-to-apply-parent-class-to-all-browserrouter-routes

Comment: @vighnesh153 yes

Comment: @YosiLeibman so I add a body tag in the JSX in the Signup component? or did you mean something else?

Comment: In which of the options?

Comment: There are multiple ways you can do this. One is using [React Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html). Second is using the router hooks by trying to match the path and add/remove css classes from the `body` element based on path.

Comment: If the router covers all the screen - go on the first option, and set bg color for the root element of each component. If no - you need to pass the route to each component, and it's too messy, so the better option will be to set the app bg color to a state, and the router will trigger the mutation.

Comment: Just implement the background you want in the `Signup` component. No need to complicate this with coupling to the router/routing/global state/etc... You've also a typo in your code snippet, `<Browser Router>` should probably be `<BrowserRouter>`. Can you edit your post to share a [mcve] for what you are trying to accomplish? As-is the question is too broad/open-ended.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick answers, I managed to do it by just adding a background in my Signup component @DrewReese , for practice wise I will try to do it with useState as well. P.S. I'm new to stackoverflow, it did not want to post my question because the code was not formatted correctly, there were red underlines under BrowserRouter, so when I separated it stack said it was ok. Don't know what that was about

Comment: @YosiLeibman I will try to do it with state now

Comment: @vighnesh153 appreciate the help bro

Comment: That might have just been your browser trying to highlight a mispelled English word? ‍♂️ It's perfectly valid in code and code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a current location check (using react router useLocation() method), and based on the desired value update css background:

`import {Route, Link, Routes, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';`

`const location = useLocation();`

`console.log('pathname', location.pathname);`